# How to set response class in FastAPI?

Tags: python, serialization, fastapi, orjson

Using [**orjson**](https://github.com/ijl/orjson) to serializing response has a remarkable effect on the speed of [fastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) restful services, specifically for very big objects. As I have read in the official [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/), we can use the response class directly as a parameter of api method. The problem is that when I use the `ORJSONResponse` directly as a function it works; however, it doesn't work when passing it into parameter `esponse_class=ORJSONResponse`.

#### 1. sample code with direct calling of `ORJSONResponse()`:

this code run in **75ms** ,size **6.6 MB** that shows orjson serialization works properly.
It's faster than .net core and it is what I need.

```
from fastapi import APIRouter

from fastapi.responses import ORJSONResponse

router=APIRouter()
__all__=["router"]

siz=1000000
ret=[None]*siz
for i in range(0,siz-1):
    ret[i]=i

@router.get("/planlist"))
def plan_list():
    ORJSONResponse(ret)
```

#### 2. sample code with passing `ORJSONResponse` as parameter:

this code runs just like without response class set. it takes **876 ms**  more than 10 times longer in the same **6.6MB** size. it shows `orjson` has not been set correctly.

```
from fastapi import APIRouter
from fastapi.responses import ORJSONResponse

router=APIRouter()
__all__=["router"]

siz=1000000
ret=[None]*siz
for i in range(0,siz-1):
    ret[i]=i

@router.get("/planlist",response_class=ORJSONResponse)
def plan_list():

    for i in range(0,siz-1):
        ret[i]=i

    return ret
```

> **Test platform**
>
> - Test client: ansomnia core 2020.4.1, same results in postman 7.34.0
> - Os: MacOS catalina 10.15.7, same results for windows 10
> - cpu: core i9

Comment: Future readers might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74173023/17865804) helpful as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also, we have documentation for [**Returning a Response Directly**](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/).

So you can use this, not a bad practice.

```py
return ORJSONResponse(content=data)
```

But this will skip the validation, serialization and automatic documentation, which will give you huge flexibility and performance but which also means, you need to make sure the contents are ready for it and you need to manually design OpenAPI schemas.

Comment: Maybe the for loop in the second example causes this huge difference. Otherwise, this is so strange.

Comment: Thanks for answering, yes in this particular case, because of large data size time is important rather than validation. so validation is mostly need in input here it is out put.

Comment: and about `for` statement, I have set it out side of the method in module global scope and when it is called data is data is ready. it cant cause big time deference .

Answer (score 0):

You can now use orjson as a default response class/type as mentioned in the [docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64408092/how-to-set-response-class-in-fastapi)

A small example

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import ORJSONResponse

app = FastAPI(default_response_class=ORJSONResponse)


@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items():
    return [{"item_id": "Foo"}]
```