# How to read the request body using orjson library in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette, orjson

I am writing code to receive a JSON payload in FastAPI.

Here is my code:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, status, Request
from fastapi.responses import ORJSONResponse
import uvicorn
import asyncio
import orjson

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/", status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def get_data(request: Request):
    param = await request.json()
    return param
```

However, what I want is `request.json()` to be used with `orjson` instead of the default `json` library of Python.
Any idea how to address this problem? Please help me, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FastAPI is very slow in returning a large amount of JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73564771/fastapi-is-very-slow-in-returning-a-large-amount-of-json-data)

Comment: it seems to be reading and then dumping a JSON file while mine is getting a payload in JSON format. In ```request.json```, it was used ```json.dumps()```, I wanna replace it with orgjson package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Reading `request` data using `orjson`

When calling `await request.json()`, FastAPI (actually Starlette) first reads the body (using the `.body()` method of the `Request` object), and then calls `json.loads()` (using the standard `json` library of Python) to return a `dict`/`list` object to you inside the endpoint (see the implementation [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/fa737beb2838f568fe2477e2316a7fdf3d3eb257/starlette/requests.py#L239))—it doesn't use `.dumps()`, as you mentioned in the comments section, as that method is used to serialise a Python object into JSON.

Hence, to read/convert the request body using `orjson` instead, you can use the below (if you would like to retrieve the raw body within a `def` instead of `async def` endpoint, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70659178/17865804)):

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
import orjson

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/')
async def submit(request: Request):
    body = await request.body()
    data = orjson.loads(body)
    return 'success'
```

### Returning `response` data using `orjson`

When returning data such as `dict`, `list`, etc,  FastAPI will automatically convert that return value into JSON, using the Python standard `json.dumps()`, after inspecting every item inside and making sure it is serializable with JSON, using the [JSON Compatible Encoder](https://nspect%20every%20item%20inside%20and%20make%20sure%20it%20is%20serializable%20with%20JSON,%20using%20the%20same%20JSON%20Compatible%20Encoder) (see [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804) for more details). Hence, if you would like to use the `orjson` library instead, you would need to send a custom `Response` directly, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73580096/17865804). Example:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
import orjson

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/')
async def submit(request: Request):
    body = await request.body()
    data = orjson.loads(body)
    return Response(orjson.dumps(data), media_type='application/json')
```

### Returning `response` data using FastAPI's `ORJSONResponse`

Alternatively, you could [use the `ORJSONResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#use-orjsonresponse) provided by FastAPI (still make sure you have the `orjson` libray installed, as well as the content that you are returning is serializable with JSON). Have a look at futher documentation [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#custom-response-class) and [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#default-response-class) on how to **customise** and/or set `ORJSONResponse` as the **default** response class (the implementation of the `ORJSONResponse` could be found [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/efc12c5cdbede6922a033a5234c70cb22c4d204a/fastapi/responses.py#L29)).

Note that when using the `response_class` parameter in the endpoint's decorator to set the `Response` class, one does not necessarily need to use that response class when returning the data from the endpoint as well. This is because FastAPI, behind the scenes, will encode/serialise the data based on the `response_class` you set, as well as use it to define the "media type" of the response. Hence, one could either set `response_class=ORJSONResponse` or `return ORJSONResponse(...)`. Having said that, it wouldn't hurt using both, as shown in the example below and in some examples provided in the official FastAPI documentation, not only for clarity purposes, but also for proper Swagger UI documentation purposes. The `response_class` will inform Swagger UI/OpenAPI docs for the expected media type of a successful response—one could confirm that by looking at the expected "Responses" and their media type under an endpoint in `/docs` (see FastAPI's documentation for declaring [additional responses in OpenAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/additional-responses/)).

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import ORJSONResponse

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/', response_class=ORJSONResponse)
async def submit(request: Request):
    body = await request.body()
    return ORJSONResponse(body.decode('utf-8'))
```

In the case of the example above, one wouldn't notice any difference in Swagger UI autodocs whether or not using the `response_class=ORJSONResponse`, as `application/json` is the default media type for FastAPI endpoints, regardless. However, in a follwoing example in this answer, where `HTMLResponse` is returned from a specific endpoint, if one didn't use `response_class=HTMLResponse`, Swagger UI/OpenAPI docs would incorrectly indicate that an `application/json` response is expected from that endpoint in case of a successful response.

#### Setting `ORJSONResponse` as the `default_response_class`

As explained in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#default-response-class), one can define the default response class for their FastAPI application, as follows. In that way, every response from FastAPI will be encoded using `ORJSONResponse` in the example below; thus, there would be no need for you to either set `response_class=ORJSONResponse` or use `return ORJSONResponse(...)`.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import ORJSONResponse

app = FastAPI(default_response_class=ORJSONResponse)


@app.get("/items")
async def read_items():
    return [{"item_id": "Foo"}]
```

You **will still be able to override** the default response class in an endpoint if needed, as shown in the examples earlier, by either setting the `response_class` parameter in the endpoint's decorator or returning that `Response` class directly, or using both methods, as explained earlier, so that Swagger UI/OpenAPI documentation is informed for the expected response type of that endpoint. For instance:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import ORJSONResponse, HTMLResponse

app = FastAPI(default_response_class=ORJSONResponse)


@app.get("/items")
async def read_items():
    return [{"item_id": "Foo"}]


@app.get("/html", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def get_html():
    html_content = """
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>HTML!</h1>
        </body>
    </html>
    """
    return HTMLResponse(content=html_content, status_code=200)
```

---

Please make sure to have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71741617/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70774077/17865804) to learn about the various approaches of sending JSON data to a FastAPI backend, and how to define an endpoint to expect and validate JSON data, instead of relying on using `await request.json()` (which is useful when the app requires passing arbitrary JSON data, but does not perform any validation on the data).