# How to alter the ouput of a get list, or use an alternate serializer in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, crud, pydantic

I'm trying to alter the content of a list view on FastAPI, depending on a get parameter. As the format is defined by a pydantic model, how can I customize it (or use an alternative model from within the view)?

Here's my view:

```py
from fastapi_pagination import Page, Params, paginate
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session


class EventSerializer(BaseModel):
    id: str
    # ...

class EventAttendeeSerializer(BaseModel):
    id: str
    event: str  # contains the event UUID
    # ...

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


@api.get("/", response_model=Page[EventAttendeeSerializer])
async def get_list(db: Session, pagination: Params = Depends(), extend: str = None):
    objects = db.query(myDbModel).all()
    if "event" in extend.split(","):
        # return EventSerializer for each object instead of id
    
    return paginate(objects, pagination)
```

At runtime, it would work like this:

```
GET /v1/event-attendees/
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": <event_attendee_id>,
            "event": <event_id>,
        }
    ],
    "total": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "size": 50,
}
```

```
GET /v1/event-attendees/?extend=event
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": <event_attendee_id>,
            "event": {
                "id": <event_id>,
                # ...
            }
        }
    ],
    "total": 1,
    "page": 1,
    "size": 50,
}
```

I searched for some kind of hooks in the pydantic and FastAPI docs and source code, but did not find anything relevant.
Anyone can help please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return data in JSON format using FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73972660/how-to-return-data-in-json-format-using-fastapi)

Comment: Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74173023/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73580096/17865804).

Comment: Not really, as I'm actually trying to avoid doing the object serialization manually and keep using fastapi/pydantic object serialization process.
In a perfect world, I'd like to be able to implement it somewhere within the serializer (but I would need to access the request from there or pass parameters).

Comment: That's a good idea, but the problem is I'm actually returning a list of models coming from database, which gets converted by the serializer.

Answer (score 1):

You can [decalre a `response_model` using `Union`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/extra-models/#union-or-anyof) (of two types) and return the model your wish if a condition is met. Since you are returning a list of objects/models, you can have [`response_model`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/) declared as a `List` of `Union`.

### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import List, Union


class Simple(BaseModel):
    id: int


class Specific(Simple):
    description: str


RESULT = {
    'id': 1,
    'description': 'test'
}


app = FastAPI()

    
@app.get('/results', response_model=List[Union[Specific, Simple]])
def get_results(specific: bool = False):
    if specific:
        results = [Specific(**RESULT)] * 2
    else:
        results = [Simple(**RESULT)] * 2

    return results
```

Using FastAPI [0.89.0+](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/releases/tag/0.89.0), you can alternatively declare the return type / [`response_model`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/) in the function [return type annotation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#return-type-and-data-filtering), for instance:

```py
@app.get('/results')
def get_results(specific: bool = False) -> List[Union[Specific, Simple]]:
    if specific:
        # ...
```

As for using alternate serialisers (as mentioned in your question), please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74173023/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73580096/17865804). You can read about how FastAPI serialises a return value by default in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That would work for a get_detail, where I would return a single object, but would force me to use a loop for list responses, which would be inefficient. That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.