# How to add extra data to pydantic schemas in FastAPI response?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

This is my Response model -

```
class BillBase(BaseModel):
    bill_no: int
    amount: int
    about: str

class ShowSalesBill(BillBase):
    id: int
    left_amount: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

so this `left_amount` int field is not in the Bills model I want to calculate this field based on some condition. My question is can we get extra fields while getting responses from the response model as we have in the Django serializer we can get some custom data under the `get_fiel_name` function there is something in FastAPI.

Comment: Create a third class that inherits from `ShowSalesBill` and has the extra field

Comment: i have to calculate that field according to bill id

Comment: Yes so make a separate class that won't be synced with your database so you can calculate the `left_amount`

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: You could specify a custom `response_model`, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71439821/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75115378/17865804), adding the extra fields you wish.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please edit it, include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and put some effort into explaining precisely what your desired output is as well as what your current actual output/error is.

Comment: @Chris  basically I have to run db query to get this left_amount