# "AttributeError: encode" when returning StreamingResponse in FastAPI

Tags: python-3.x, streaming, fastapi, server-sent-events, openai-api

I am using Python 3.10 and FastAPI `0.92.0` to write a Server-Sent Events (SSE) stream api. This is how the Python code looks like:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, FastAPI, Header

from src.chat.completions import chat_stream
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse

router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/v1/completions",response_class=StreamingResponse)
def stream_chat(q: str, authorization: str = Header(None)):
    auth_mode, auth_token = authorization.split(' ')
    if auth_token is None:
        return "Authorization token is missing"
    answer = chat_stream(q, auth_token)
    return StreamingResponse(answer, media_type="text/event-stream")
```

and this is the `chat_stream` function:

```
import openai

def chat_stream(question: str, key: str):
    openai.api_key = key
    # create a completion
    completion = openai.Completion.create(model="text-davinci-003",
                                          prompt=question,
                                          stream=True)
    return completion
```

When I am using this command to invoke the api:

```
curl -N -H "Authorization: Bearer sk-the openai key" https://chat.poemhub.top/v1/completions?q=hello
```

the server side shows the following error:

```
INFO:     123.146.17.54:0 - "GET /v1/completions?q=hello HTTP/1.0" 200 OK
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/h11_impl.py", line 429, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 276, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 69, in app
    await response(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/starlette/responses.py", line 270, in __call__
    async with anyio.create_task_group() as task_group:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/anyio/_backends/_asyncio.py", line 662, in __aexit__
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/starlette/responses.py", line 273, in wrap
    await func()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/starlette/responses.py", line 264, in stream_response
    chunk = chunk.encode(self.charset)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/openai/openai_object.py", line 61, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(*err.args)
AttributeError: encode
```

Why did this error happen? What should I do to fixed it?

Comment: I have already tried what you said to transfer the response to bytes, seems did not work. I am doing it like this right now: `def chat_stream(question: str, key: str):
    openai.api_key = key
    completion = openai.Completion.create(model="text-davinci-003",
                                          prompt=question,
                                          stream=True)
    for _ in completion:
        yield f"data:{json.dumps(_)}\n\n"` so I am not sure the problem is what you said. @Chris

Comment: I think it maybe the encode issue. you can paste your answer and I will try it and also give other people some clue to avoid this problem. @Chris

Comment: Sincere thanks for your valuable time and I will tried what you said. @Chris

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As described in [FastAPI's documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#streamingresponse), [`StreamingResponse`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/62b5b6042a39289ed561580c251c233250c3c088/starlette/responses.py#L228) takes an asynchronous (`async def`) generator or a normal (`def`) generator/iterator and streams the response body. As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73843234/17865804), in either case, FastAPI will still work asynchronously—if the generator that is passed to `StreamingResponse` isn't asynchronous, FastAPI/Starlette will then run the generator in a separate thread (see the relevant implementation [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/62b5b6042a39289ed561580c251c233250c3c088/starlette/responses.py#L239)), using [`iterate_in_threadpool()`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/62b5b6042a39289ed561580c251c233250c3c088/starlette/concurrency.py#L58), which will then be `await`ed (see `iterate_in_threadpool()` implementation). For more details on `def` vs `async def` in FastAPI, as well as solutions for running blocking operations inside `async def` endpoints, please have a look at this [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804).

`StreamingResponse`, a subclass of `Response`, streams the response body in `bytes`. Hence, if the content passed through the generator is not in `bytes` format, FastAPI/Starlette will attempt to encode/convert it into `bytes` (using the [default `utf-8` encoding scheme](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/62b5b6042a39289ed561580c251c233250c3c088/starlette/responses.py#L41)). Below is a code snippet from the [relevant implementation](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/62b5b6042a39289ed561580c251c233250c3c088/starlette/responses.py#L262):

```py
async for chunk in self.body_iterator:
    if not isinstance(chunk, bytes):
        chunk = chunk.encode(self.charset)
    await send({"type": "http.response.body", "body": chunk, "more_body": True})
```

However, if a `chunk` in the iterator/generator is not in `str` format that could be encoded, an `AttributeError` will be raised (e.g., `AttributeError: ... has no attribute 'encode'`), similar to what is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804) (see Option 2, Note 3). Also, if a chunk includes characters outside the range of `utf-8` encoding, you might as well be faced with `UnicodeEncodeError: ... codec can't encode character`. Thus, given the `AttributeError: encode` in the error traceback you provided, it is very likely that you are passing an object other than `str`.

The example below demonstrates an asynchronous generator (i.e., `async def gen()`), streaming JSON data, which, in this case, requires `dict` objects first to be converted into `str` (using `json.dumps()`, or any other JSON encoder, such as `orjson`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74173023/17865804)) and then, **optionally**, to the corrsponding byte value (using `.encode('utf-8')`), which, as explained earlier, if omitted, FastAPI/Starlette will take care of that. In addition, the example below uses `text/event-stream` media type (also known as [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)), which is usually used when [sending events from the server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#sending_events_from_the_server) (see [event stream format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events#event_stream_format) as well). If you are confident that the data sent from the server are always in JSON format, you could use `application/json` media type as well. Note that, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75760884/17865804), using `text/plain` media type instead might result in not displaying the streaming data in the browser immediately, as browsers use to buffer `text/plain` responses for what is called "MIME Sniffing" (see the linked answer above on how to disable it, if you would like to use `text/plain`).

### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
import asyncio
import json

app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/')
async def main():
    async def gen():
        while True:
            #yield (json.dumps({'msg': 'Hello World!'}) + '\n\n').encode('utf-8')
            # or, simply use the below, and FastAPI/Starlette will take care of the encoding
            yield json.dumps({'msg': 'Hello World!'}) + '\n\n'
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

    return StreamingResponse(gen(), media_type='text/event-stream')
```

If you are confident that the data sent from the server are in **JSON** format, you could instead use:

```py
# ...

@app.get('/')
async def main():
    async def gen():
        while True:
            yield json.dumps({'msg': 'Hello World!'})
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

    return StreamingResponse(gen(), media_type='application/json')
```

Comment: There is an interesting blog post [streaming-with-fastapi](https://www.vidavolta.io/streaming-with-fastapi/) where the writer supports that the suitable media_type is `'application/x-ndjson'`. Do you have further knowledge if setting up media type to `'application/json'` or `application/x-ndjson` improves performance instead of `'text/event-stream'`? Of course we suppose that data would be always in json format.