# How to send part of response as and when ready in FastAPI

Tags: python-3.x, backend, fastapi, large-language-model

I want to design my API in FastAPI, such that I can send part of response as and when it's ready and at end, when final response is ready, I want to send that.

I've tried using BackgroundTasks, but I was unable to do it:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response, BackgroundTasks
from typing import Generator, Union
import asyncio

app = FastAPI()

class LLMResponse:
    def __init__(self, content: str, status: str, completion: bool):
        self.content = content
        self.status = status
        self.completion = completion

    def __iter__(self):
        yield f"data: {self.content}\n\n"

        if self.completion:
            yield "event: completionStatus\ndata: {}\n\n".format(self.status)

async def llm_task(response: Response):
    # Simulate a long-running LLM task
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    yield LLMResponse("First response", "Processing", False)

    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    yield LLMResponse("Second response", "Processing", False)

    await asyncio.sleep(15)
    yield LLMResponse("Final response", "Completed", True)

@app.get("/poll", response_class=Response)
async def poll(response: Response, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    # Set response headers for streaming
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/event-stream"
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["Connection"] = "keep-alive"

    # Start the long-running task in the background
    background_tasks.add_task(stream_llm_responses, response)

    return response

async def stream_llm_responses(response: Response):
    async for llm_response in llm_task(response):
        for chunk in llm_response:
            await response.body_iter.write(chunk.encode())
            await response.body_iter.flush()
```

Can you help me to work it?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75760884/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: Related answers could also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75837557/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70626324/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71871482/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71738644/17865804)

Comment: Thank you for your response @Chris. But, I have 2 doubts here :
1. If I go with StreamingResponse, is it optimized enough for concurrency or handling multiple parallel users?

2. For integrating this StreamingResponse in React, which way is better. Is EventSource API is better idea or something else?